# save informations in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

i have 5 items in my page with 3 information. (for example, name and price and number )
i want when i click on them (for example item 1) for first time, create an object and save items information to localStorage and for another times increase the number of item in localstorage.

```
    function() {
    items.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            let exist = localStorage.getItem('name');
            var name =
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].textContent;
            localStorage.setItem('name', name);
            var price =
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[2].textContent;
            localStorage.setItem('price', price);

            var number = localStorage.getItem('number');
            number = parseInt(number);
            if (number) {
                localStorage.setItem('number', number + 1);
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('number', 1)
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

its my code, but when i click on any item, previeos details in localstorage will be lost and information of new item replaced.
how i can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling `localStorage.setItem('name', name)` you are overwriting the previous value of `name`. To store all names, prices, and numbers you have to use array. But, `localStorage` supports nothing but string. So before writing, you have to convert the array to a string, and upon reading you have to revert the string back to an array.

```js
function() {
    items.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            let names = localStorage.getItem('name');
            const exists = !!names;
            names = exists ? JSON.parse(names) : [];
            let prices = exists ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('price')): [];
            let numbers = exists ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number')) : [];
            var name =
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].textContent;
            const nI = names.indexOf(name);
            if (nI === -1) {
                names.push(name);
                localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(names));
                var price =
                event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[2].textContent;

                prices.push(price);
                localStorage.setItem('price', JSON.stringify(prices));
                numbers.push(1);
            } else {
                // else they are already in localStorage, just increase number                
                numbers[nI]++;
            }
            localStorage.setItem('number', JSON.stringify(numbers));
        });
    });
})();
```